# Asana user photo API request misses photo field in json response

Tags: asana

We make requests to the [Asana API](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/) for user photo `opt_field`. We constructed the asana users query like this:

```
https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/users\?opt_fields\=name,email,photo,workspaces
```

The reponse returned is

```
    data =     (
            {
        email = "user2@gmail.com";
        id = xxooiio1664;
        name = "User 2";
        workspaces =             (
                            {
                id = 104764788xxxyyy;
            },
                            {
                id = 4983461zzzjjjj;
            }
        );
    },
```

But the photo field has been missing. Did we miss anything in the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `opt_fields`, it *only* returns fields you *explicitly* request, and each of the images is considered its own field for this purpose. So you would need to specify e.g. `opt_fields=photo.image_60x60`.

Comment: is the request rate limit of 100 imposed include photos downloading?

Comment: No, the request limit only applies to API calls (anything with `/api/` in the path) - the photo downloads are separate. There are additional abuse prevention tools that may limit you, in theory, but those requests don't count agains the API rate limit.